# JSON, PHP and REST Web services

Tags: php, jquery, json, rest

I'm new with this, so please be patient... (I'll write it just like the code was given to me)... I'm working on PHP files with .js files attached (if somehow this could be helpfull), this is a CRM insertion.

I need to consume a REST web service from:

```
http://example.com:8080/path/to/folder
```

From a PHP (POST method) form, I need to send a JSON with the data (this could be also be send with jQuery):

```
{
"name": "Name",
"lastname": "Last Name",
"email": "name@example.com", (need to be validated on PHP)
"phone": "19283764", (need to be validated on PHP)
"source": "eCommerce",
"credential": "no"
}
```

And get this response:

```
{
"response":[X]{
"result":[X]{
"message": "Record(s) added successfully",
"recorddetail":[X]{
"FL":[ ][{"content": 5646542168321358, "val": "Id" }, {"content": "2017-06-30 11:25:17",…]
}
},
"uri": "/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords"
}
}
```

If someone could please give me an example of how to achive this, that would be awesome. Or instruction where and what to write in every file would be appreciated too.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: don't you know how to send post request to server using jQuery?

Comment: @SarathKumar, I just know some programming basic stuff, but something like this not. Thanks for the reply...

Comment: Study some php / ajax tutorials. Question is far too broad. You need to break it down into smaller tasks and deal with that sequence of tasks one at a time

Comment: What is `FL` in response JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php you can make this with curl or you can send your data in the url like this.

```
$json = array(
    "name"=>"Name",
    "lastname"=>"Last Name",
    "email"=>"name@example.com",
    "phone"=>"19283764", 
    "source"=>"eCommerce",
    "credential"=>"no"
)
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://example.com:8080/path/to/folder?json=$json"));
echo $response;
```

And in the other end that is receiving this

```
$email = $_GET["json"]["email"];
$phone = $_GET["json"]["phone"];

$json = '{
    "response":[X]{
    "result":[X]{
    "message": "Record(s) added successfully",
    "recorddetail":[X]{
    "FL":[ ][{"content": 5646542168321358, "val": "Id" }, {"content": "2017-06-30 11:25:17",…]
    }
    },
    "uri": "/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords"
    }
    }';

echo json_encode($json);
```

In jquery.

```
var json = {
    "name": "Name",
    "lastname": "Last Name",
    "email": "name@example.com", 
    "phone": "19283764",
    "source": "eCommerce",
    "credential": "no"
}

$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com:8080/path/to/folder",
    type: "POST",
    data: json,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
)};
```

if you are using this jquery method you must use $_POST["json"] instead of $_GET["json"]

Answer (score -1):

**Sending a JSON to server and parsing output from server**:

```
var data={name:"Oliver",last_name:"Schael",phone:2445}
$.post("http://example.com:8080/path/to/folder",data,function(response){
  var json_output=JSON.parse(response);
});
```

Comment: where should I paste this code and how do I call it from the PHP form? The JSON data should be taken from the PHP from too...

Comment: This is a jQuery code. So you have to paste in the script section.

Comment: How do I call the script form the PHP Submit form and taking the variables from it?

Comment: This **does not** send ***json*** as claimed and there is no `$.POST()`. javascript is case sensitive